# How to iterate over enum from second index while getting string value in TypeScript 3?

Tags: angular, typescript, enums, iterator

Given an simple enum in Typescript:

```
enum Test {
  entryA = 1,
  entryB,
  entryC,
  entryD
}
```

I know I can get the string values from the enum with following code snippet:

```
Test[Test.entryA] // returns "entryA" as string
```

I want to start at the second index from the enum (entryB) in a loop:

```
for (const s of someArray) {
    const d: SomeType = {
      option: ,// here I want to save the string value from enum beginning at the second index = 2
      value: s,
    };
}
```

The array I loop through and the enum beginning at the second index have the same number of entries.

I cannot figure out how to get this work when thinking about iterating enums as usual:

```
for (const test in Test) {
  if (!Number(test)) {
      console.log(test);
  }
}

// entryA
// entryB
// entryC
// entryD
```

Anyone knows how to combine this for getting rid of my problem? :)

Comment: `Object.keys(Test).filter(key => !Number(key)).slice(1)`

Comment: Works for me :). Thanks